# How to get the SharePoint workflow status for each SP item with a PowerShell script?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

The workflow status data that I want is in the column with the same name as the document library. However I cannot access the data in that column with the name for that column displayed in SharePoint. I need the internal column name if I am going to access that column with the code below.

```
$list = $SPWeb.lists["document library name here"]

$items = $list.Items

$count = 0

foreach($item in $items)
{

    # (typically you put the column name you want where SPWorkflowStatusColumnName is)
    if($item["SPWorkflowStatusColumnName"] -eq "Completed")
    {
         $count = $count + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal Column name is eight character long removing spaces and non-alphanumeric characters.

or to find the internal name of the column just click on the column name in list and check the url value after SortField= will be the internal name of the column.

for eg. in my case usrl looks like this:
http://[server]/[sitecollection]/[site]/listname/Forms/AllItems.aspx?View={view GUID}&SortField=TradingS&SortDir=Asc

and my fields internal name is "TradingS".

Comment: That worked for the columns that I could already get information from but it didn't work for the column I described above. That is a helpful tip though!